# How unsafe is to use ctrl+c or ctrl+d in mysql prompt?

Tags: mysql, security

How unsafe is to use <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd> when in `mysql` prompt whether to interrupt a hanging statement or <kbd>ctrl + d</kbd> to exit?

When I do <kbd>ctr + d</kbd> for exit `mysql` can see a ¿special character? typed besides `Bye`

```
mysql> ^DBye
```

Doing <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd> for exit `mysql`

```
mysql> Ctrl-C -- exit!
Aborted
```

Doing <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd> to cancel or interrupt a query with a huge row impression

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM db.table ORDER BY column DESC;
........
........
........
........
Ctrl-C -- sending "KILL QUERY 126537" to server ...
Ctrl-C -- query aborted.
```

But when trying to re-execute an improved query

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM db.table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 10;
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
```

Need to execute again and no error's returned.

I want to know if there's some security or safety stuff related to this.

Comment: More details, please.

Comment: @RickJames updated

Comment: ^C aborts the query, as you see.  ^D is "end-of-file", which terminates the commandline mysql (but not the server, mysqld).

Comment: `ORDER BY` will take a long time if there are millions of rows.  The `ORDER BY` must finish before `LIMIT` can take effect, so the query takes time with or without the `LIMIT`.

Comment: I use ^C a lot; it is "harmless" on `SELECTs`.